# Does a bitcoinj SPV node forward transactions for itself?

Tags: bitcoinj, spv

The bitcoinj library offers a rather convenient [WalletAppKit](http://code.google.com/p/bitcoinj/source/browse/core/src/main/java/com/google/bitcoin/kits/WalletAppKit.java?r=ee0b56180b1826313a22781fc652101a68ea7f17) class, which I'd like to accept payments from customers. In order to facilitate the payments I'd offer the customers to send the transaction directly to me, instead of sending it to the Bitcoin Network and eventually reaching me.

If the simple example from WalletAppKit receives a payment that transfers some coins to one of its own wallets, does it announce the transaction to its peers and provides them with the transaction, or does the SPV protocol dictate that the node is a mere consumer of information?

If it does not forward the transactions, what would be the required modifications to allow transaction forwarding?